# What happened to my comment?

Tags: discussion

Did my comment get deleted from the [Why does Peter Jackson totally suck?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35031/why-did-peter-jackson-significanty-change-the-story-line-in-the-lord-of-the-ring) question? I got a notification that **DVK** had replied to my comment, but when I clicked on the link I found there are no comments at all. Are we not allowed to comment on questions with a lot of downvotes? Or something? I ask because I thought my comment was on topic to the question. Was it not?

**What happened to my comment**?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a mod decided the comments weren't going anywhere constructive and purged all of them. There's a single option for that, much easier than going through and deciding which are worth keeping and which aren't. Comments are not meant to be permanent, which is why only mods can see deleted ones (and even that took some convincing on the part of the team).  Yours probably wouldn't have been deleted on its own, but it happened to get swept up in the purge.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for explaining. I hadn't realized more comments had been made.

Comment: @Slytherincess Pretty much the entire comment thread was obsoleted by DVK's edits, so I removed them all when I reopened the question.

Comment: @Keen - Okay. I didn't know that DVK had edited.

Comment: @Slytherincess - *Stealtho Editio*

Comment: Per the usual disclaimer ***"Comments can be deleted by moderators for any reason and none"***